# How many colors can a single pixel can have?

Tags: image, pixel

I am new in image processing. Color pictures usually have 3 channels: Red, Green, Blue. I also understand that they can have different intensities. So is a pixel only one color (red, green, or blue) with intensity? or is each pixel a combination of those 3 colors with different intensities for each color?

Comment: It depends on the bitmap format.

Comment: The most common is that you would get 3 values for each pixel, a red one with 8 bits meaning up to 256 intensities, a green one with up to 256 intensities and a blue one with up to 256 intensities. Altogether, that allows 16.7 million colours in total. Sometimes you get a fourth value too, which represents transparency - notably not available in JPEG. Some formats allow 16-bit samples (PNG, TIFF, NetPBM mainly), some formats allow 32-bit samples (TIFF mainly).